# MQPUT while using MQCB : MQRC_HCONN_ASYNC_ACTIVE

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

Our process needs to read messages from a topic on the local Q manager and also write to a different topic on the same local Q manager.

To read messages we have used `MQCB`. The messages reach the callback function of the process. However, while the callback remains registered, we are not able to `MQPUT` messages to a different topic.

We get an error that says: 
`2500 : MQRC_HCONN_ASYNC_ACTIVE`
`An attempt to issue an MQI call has been made while the connection is started`

Apparently, a single connection handle cannot be used to both read and write. We have to Suspend the `MQCB`, `MPUT` the message and Resume the `MQCB` to get it to work.

Is there a way to avoid having to suspend and resume?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the expected behavior when using MQCB. Two approaches you can take:

1) Create another connection to the same queue manager to publish messages.
2) If your design is to publish messages whenever you receive a message on the callback function, then publish messages from callback function itself.

**Update**

MQRC_ALREADY_CONNECTED (2002) issue: What MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_* option have you used? Suggest you to use MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK option to get around this problem. I wrote a sample program and created two connections on the same thread by using MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK option.

Comment: We tried the 1st approach to create 2 connections to the same queue manager. The point is here we can have only 1 connection per queue manager per process. If we try to create another connection it gives a warning that the connection to queue manager already exists and gives the same connection handle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Shashi. We created two connections using MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK as connection options. thanks a lot.